# Nativescript camera module: is there a way to let user choose picture from gallery?

Tags: nativescript

I have an app where the user can create an account and take a picture of himself to use as an avatar. I'm obviously using Camera module for that. Now I would like to add an option for user to choose an existing picture from the device gallery, but I've been unable to find such functionality neither in build-in Camera module or any 3-rd party plugin. I'm looking something  similar to Cordova camera plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera, where one can specify PictureSourceType and on getPicture the app will show the gallery and the user can choose a picture from there, then callback will return base64-encoded string or URI for the image file. Thanks ahead for any insights!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes use this plugin https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker
 To select from the device.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. That's what I was looking for. Unfortunately the plugin seems broken and mostly unusable. Anyway this is better then nothing. Hope main issues will be fixed soon.

Comment: If looking for another ANDROID option, I wrapped a native lib into a plugin here: https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-telegram-image-picker

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! I managed to make nativescript-imagepicker work on iOS, but had issues with Android (it never returns for me from gallery to the app just hanging). So, now I can just use your plugin for Android!